# How do "inner" and "outer" work in this bubble sort code?

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, nested-loops, bubble-sort

I am trying to learn the bubble sort algorithm in a book for C. I can't seem to understand in the code below how `int outer` and `int inner` link to which element of the `nums` array. Like how does `inner` become `nums[0]` while `outer` becomes `nums[1]` (if I'm correct), then progresses through the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
    int nums[10];
    time_t t;

    srand(time(&t));

    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {
        nums[ctr] = (rand() % 99) + 1;
    }

    puts("\n Here is the list before the sort: ");
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", nums[ctr]);
    }

    for (outer = 0; outer < 9; outer++)
    {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (inner = outer; inner < 10; inner++)
        {
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer])
            {
                temp = nums[inner];
                nums[inner] = nums[outer];
                nums[outer] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    puts("\n Here is the list after the sort: ");
    for ( ctr = 0; ctr < 10; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", nums[ctr]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `inner` and `outer` are just array indexes. `nums[inner]` is the array element at that position.

Comment: Also `inner = outer` seems pointless. Why compare an element with itself? `inner = outer + 1` would seem better.

Comment: Obligatory note: Insertion sort is practically always better than bubble sort. Do yourself a favor and learn to implement it (equally simple), try to forget how to implement bubble sort...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to learn the bubble sort algorithm in a book for C.

For starters if the presented code is indeed from a book then I advice to stop reading the book because it seems the author of the book is a low-qualified programmer.

The presented method is not the bubble sort method.

It looks like the selection sort method with redundant swaps.
And moreover the code contains a serious bug.

For example take an array like

```
int nums[] = { 0, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
```

and the array will not be sorted!

What is the inner loop doing?

It travers the array after the current element `nums[outer]` and if it finds an element `nums[inner]` that is less than `nums[outer]` it swaps the elements and sets the flag `didSwap` to 1 (the flag means that some elements were swapped and the outer loop shall continue its iterations)

```
        if (nums[inner] < nums[outer])
        {
            temp = nums[inner];
            nums[inner] = nums[outer];
            nums[outer] = temp;
            didSwap = 1;
        }
    }
```

Otherwise if there are no swaps then the control exits the outer loop

```
    if (didSwap == 0)
    {
        break;
    }
```

However the selection sort method must continue its iteration even if for the current `nums[outer]` there was not found an element `nums[inner]` less than `nums[outer]`.

Here is a demonstration program that shows that the presented sort method (that is not the bubble sort method) does not work.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int ctr, inner, outer, didSwap, temp;
    int nums[3] = { 1, 3, 2 };

    for (outer = 0; outer < 2; outer++)
    {
        didSwap = 0;
        for (inner = outer; inner < 3; inner++)
        {
            if (nums[inner] < nums[outer])
            {
                temp = nums[inner];
                nums[inner] = nums[outer];
                nums[outer] = temp;
                didSwap = 1;
            }
        }
        if (didSwap == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    puts("\n Here is the list after the sort: ");
    for ( ctr = 0; ctr < 3; ctr++)
    {
        printf("%i\n", nums[ctr]);
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
 Here is the list after the sort: 
1
3
2
```

As you can see the array was not sorted.:)

Answer (score 2):

`inner` never becomes `nums[0]`. `inner` and `outer` are array indexes, so when `inner` is `0`, `nums[inner]` is `nums[0]`.

The code that performs the comparison and swapping never does that with `inner` and `outer`, it uses `nums[inner]` and `nums[outer]`.

```
        if (nums[inner] < nums[outer])
        {
            temp = nums[inner];
            nums[inner] = nums[outer];
            nums[outer] = temp;
            didSwap = 1;
        }
```